# Emulator is turning off my ethernet connection

Tags: windows-phone-8, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am learning windows phone programming, when I run emulator it turns off ethernet connection on my laptop, but wifi still works.

How to fix it?

May be it is Hyper-V trouble?

Ethernet controller: RealTek PCIe GBE

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is just removing the Emulator customization of the network connections and then allowing it to restore them!

- On the host computer, open the Hyper-V Manager
- Click Action -> Virtual Switch Manager
- Remove the 3 Virtual Switches that show up on the list

After this step the internet connection show have been restored; the next time you open the Emulator it will then allow you to re-add those virtual switches back.

**Attention:** Please be aware that you may have more entries if Hyper-V is actually used by another app than the Windows Phone Emulator!